# Window Developement & Installation Steps

Tags: java, cordova, window

I am a newbie in Window developement.

1) I need complete setup and requirement tools need to run hello world app in window mobile.

2) Running Hybrid App (cordova) for window mobile

I have following configuration in my window based system

```
Window 10
4 GB RAM
HDD 500 GB
```

Comment: Did this answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

One way under Windows is to start developing cordova Apps with Visual Studio TACO (Tools for Apache Cordova).

Start by downloading the free Visual Studio 2015 Community [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/post-download-vs?sku=community&clcid=0x407) and choose the "Cross Plattform Mobile Development" part to be installed. With that you have everything to start development.

Create a new cordova project in Visual Studio File->New Project and in the window choose on the left side Templates->Javascript->Apache Cordova Apps and give your first project a name and create it.

Now you have a "Hello World!" App which you can run on different plattforms.

This [link](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/get-started-first-mobile-app/) will show you how to enhance your first App.

For sure you do not need Visual Studio and you can just install plain cordova [here](https://cordova.apache.org/), but I found VS very helpful.

Hope this helps.